# Get type of value within JSON object using Groovy

Tags: java, arrays, json, groovy, jsonslurper

I'm having the following JSON object which I want to check

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper() 
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;

def object = jsonSlurper.parseText '''
{
  "id" : 10,
  "docType" : "PDF",
  "values" : {
      "color" : "red",
      "pages" : 2,
    },
  "versions" : [
    {
      "verNum" : 1,
      "desc" : "This is the description for it"
    }
  ]
}
'''
// def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText("""[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "x": true}, {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6, "d": "Hello"}]""")
// def content = object.collectEntries{ 
//    it.collectEntries{ 
//        [it.key, it.value.class.name] 
//    } 
//}

//println content
```

I want to iterate through each of the keys and check for the type using Groovy, for example:
id - java.lang.Integer, docType - java.lang.String, values.color - java.lang.String, verNum within the object within the array will be java.lang.Integer

I have searched for a few different ways but most of them won't work in my case. One of them are now commented on as in the code above.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''
{
  "id" : 10,
  "docType" : "PDF",
  "values" : {
      "color" : "red",
      "pages" : 2,
    },
  "versions" : [
    {
      "verNum" : 1,
      "desc" : "This is the description for it"
    }
  ]
}
'''

def res = [:]
def traverser
traverser = { Map m ->
  m.each{ k, v ->   
    switch( v ){
      case Map:
        res[ k ] = Map
        traverser v
        break
      case List:
        res[ k ] = List
        v.each traverser
        break
      default:
        res[ k ] = v?.getClass()
    }
  }
}

traverser object

def simple = res.collectEntries{ k, v -> [ k, v.simpleName ] }
assert simple.toString() == '[id:Integer, docType:String, values:Map, color:String, pages:Integer, versions:List, verNum:Integer, desc:String]'
```

Comment: Work great! Legend!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use data variable instead of object in your sample.

```
def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText("""[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "x": true}, {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6, "d": "Hello"}]""");

def content = data.collectEntries{ 
    it.collectEntries{ 
        [it.key, it.value.class.name];
    } 
}

println content;
```

The output will be;

```
[a:java.lang.Integer, b:java.lang.Integer, c:java.lang.Integer, x:java.lang.Boolean, d:java.lang.String]
```